# Using struct from a module inside another module in Julia

Tags: import, module, julia, ijulia-notebook

I have found similar questions on SO but none of them seem to give an answer that works for my case.

I have a few modules, in one of them I create a mutable struct which I want to be able to use in the others. All files are at the same level:

- file_module_A.jl
- file_module_B.jl
- file_module_C.jl

In file_module_A.jl:

```
module A
   mutable struct MyType
      variable
   end
end
```

In file_module_B.jl:

```
module B
    # I need to import MyType here
end
```

In file_module_C.jl:

```
module C
    # I need to import MyType here
end
```

I have tried the followings without success:

- Using directly: `using .A` doesn't work
- I can't use: `include("./file_module_A.jl")` in both B and C because when they interact between each other I get the error can't convert from Main.B.A to Main.C.A since `include` includes a copy of the whole code

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `using ..A`. `using .A` means to look for `A` in the current module (`B` in the example below), and you need an extra `.` to step up one module level, to `Main` if you run the example in the REPL:

```
module A
    mutable struct MyType
        variable
    end
end

module B
    using ..A: MyType
end
```